# NodeJS Crypto encryption to front end javascript decryption

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I'm looking for AES256 CBC decryption client side,

in nodeJS I use this function to encrypt:

```
exports.encrypt = function(txt, cryptkey){
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc',cryptkey);
  var crypted = cipher.update(txt,'utf8','hex');
  crypted += cipher.final('hex');

  console.log(crypted);
  return crypted;

};
```

but I can't seem to work with it in any client side library (JSAES.js, SJCL.js, pidcrypt)

my guess is it has something to do with the base64/hex encoding decoding, any pointers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please have a look at the [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js) project:

Here is an example of AES256 CBC encryption / decryption:

**Include:**

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/mode-cfb-min.js"></script>
```

**JS:**

```
var passPhrase = "Secret Phassphrase";

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", passPhrase, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB });
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, passPhrase, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB });

console.log('encrypted', encrypted);
console.log('decrypted', decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

View the demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zCaXT/)

Comment: I included the "mode-cfb-min.js" on the server nodeJS and was able to encrypt cryptoJS server side AND client side, thanks!! :)

Comment: is it safe to store passPhrase at client side? Further, is it the same pass phrase we are using in encrypt function's parameter cryptkey?

Comment: 1.) No, it is not safe to store it on the client side. The above code is just for demo purpose.

2.) Check the documentation https://github.com/brix/crypto-js :)