# How to independence inject Browserify Crypto in Angular Ionic

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, browserify

I new bee of Ionic and angular. I used Browserify to require Crypto module of nodejs for my Ionic project. Following are my steps:

1. I added new line to app.js file

> angular.module(.....).constant('Crypto',require('crypto'))

2. I run the command line, which create new file perfectly with code of Crypto module and app.js file

> browserify app.js > bundle.js

3. I replace app.js by bundle.js in index.html file
4. I try to test it in service.js

> angular.module('mapp.services').factory('abc',['$http','Crypto',function($http,Crypto){
>       return {
>           getAllProduct:function(){                      console.log(Crypto.SHA256("Message"));
>               });
>           }   }]);

It return message "Crypto.SHA256 is not a function". I think that "constant" means a value, not a static object, so that I cannot pass Crypto to "constant". So, how can I require all needed modules at app.js file by Browserify and then pass use it at other js file, like $http?
Thanks!

Comment: You can get a more useful error message in the console if you do `console.dir(Crypto)` instead of trying to call a function that may not exist, this will let you see the actual javascript objects that the `require('Crypto')` call actually injected into your application via browserify.

Comment: I added console.dir(Crypto). It return "0     977846   dir". What it means? And I think that if I push it to "angular.module(.....).constant('Crypto',require('crypto'))", the system will consider it as simple value only, right?

Comment: It looks like it tried to import a wrapper to a native system call and failed. Basically all Crypto is doing on the server is wrapping OpenSSL so trying to convert it t for browser use is just creating a string like you see with a file pointer and *not* a Crypto object that can perform actual encryption functions. You need to switch libraries to make what you're doing work.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry because of my stupid question. The fact that we can assign Crypto object to constant pool. The problem is my code. To encrypt a string, the code must be

> crypto.createHash('sha256').update(mystr).digest('base64');

instead of

> crypto.sha256(mystr)

Now problem solved, but thanks for your all reply and comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Crypto will work on the client, it's the server-side library for performing encryption and is largely a wrapper around OpenSSL ([see here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto)).

The functions that it wraps cannot be called in Ionic/Angular for the simple reason that they aren't available on the client.

Try using [CryptoJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15055093/808532) instead as was proposed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15055093/808532) - it was designed to be used client-side like in your Ionic/Angular project to perform cryto-related operations.

Comment: I used [Browserify](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjg5ur2nK_HAhXDCo4KHbOECI4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbrowserify.org%2F&ei=ylvRVeDZDsOVuASziaLwCA&usg=AFQjCNEOwl4eO-QewxOy_9Np60mxDj97oQ&sig2=DE3igkBXC9z1D6hemOyjPw&bvm=bv.99804247,d.c2E).

Comment: Browserify is only able to convert purely javascript libraries for use in the browser, Crypto depends on server libraries written in C++ that can't be converted. I don't think Crypto will work with browserify. I suggest trying either the CryptoJS library I linked instead or another pure javascript library that has the functions you want.

Comment: @supper aban: it working for me too, CryptoJS give me a wrong result!